# retrieve user function returns [object object]

Tags: supabase

I was trying to get the user with the supabase function `const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser()` but when i print the value returned from the api call shows [object object] so i had to implement `JSON.stringify` method to get the object properly. The user is only returned into app.js, but not in other views.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    userHasAvailableHoursCreated();
  },[]);

  const userHasAvailableHoursCreated = async() => {
    const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser()   
    console.log('userId: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
  }
```